# Attempting Python list comprehension with two variable of different ranges

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to generate a list quickly with content from two different arrays of size n and n/2. As an example:

```
A = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I wish to generate something like

```
[(A[x], B[y]) for x in range(len(A)) for y in range(len(B))]
```

I understand the second for statement is the nested for loop after the "x" one. I'm trying to get the contents of the new array to be

```
A[0], B[0]
A[1], B[1]
A[2], B[2]
A[3], B[3]
A[4], B[0]
A[5], B[1]
A[6], B[2]
A[7], B[3]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use nested loops; you are pairing up `A` and `B`, with `B` repeating as needed. What you need is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (to do the pairing), and [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) (to repeat `B`):

```
from itertools import cycle

zip(A, cycle(B))
```

If `B` is always going to be half the size of `A`, you could also just double `B`:

```
zip(A, B + B)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> A = [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
>>> B = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> zip(A, cycle(B))
[(70, 1), (60, 2), (50, 3), (40, 4), (30, 1), (20, 2), (10, 3), (0, 4)]
>>> zip(A, B + B)
[(70, 1), (60, 2), (50, 3), (40, 4), (30, 1), (20, 2), (10, 3), (0, 4)]
```

For cases where it is not known which one is the longer list, you could use `min()` and `max()` to pick which one to cycle:

```
zip(max((A, B), key=len), cycle(min((A, B), key=len))
```

or for an arbitrary number of lists to pair up, cycle them *all* but use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to limit things to the maximum length:

```
inputs = (A, B)  # potentially more
max_length = max(len(elem) for elem in inputs)
zip(*(islice(cycle(elem), max_length) for elem in inputs))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> inputs = (A, B)  # potentially more
>>> max_length = max(len(elem) for elem in inputs)
>>> zip(*(islice(cycle(elem), max_length) for elem in inputs))
[(70, 1), (60, 2), (50, 3), (40, 4), (30, 1), (20, 2), (10, 3), (0, 4)]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. I tried using the zip() function but I was only receiving pairs up to len(B). I had no idea I could do zip(A, B + B).

Comment: @A.K.: `zip()` terminates at the shortest length. The trick then is to make `A` the shortest.

Comment: Another way for the arbitrary number case, using islice on the **outside** of the zip: `list(islice(zip(*map(cycle, inputs)), max(map(len, inputs))))`.

Answer (score 10):

`[(A[x % len(A)], B[x % len(B)]) for x in range(max(len(A), len(B)))]`

This will work whether or not A is the larger list. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try using only one for loop instead of two and having the second wrap back to 0 once it gets past its length.

```
[(A[x], B[x%len(B)]) for x in range(len(A))]
```

Note that this will only work if A is the longer list. If you know B will always be half the size of A you can also use this:

```
list(zip(A, B*2))
```